# Is this the same? 'run me out' and 'run out on me'

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Could you explain word-usage of 'run me out'. I think it means the same as 
'You can't just run out on her.' What verbs work in the same ways? I mean - Are there some general rules in gramma about that.

> I toId you nobody runs me out.

I see that below the meaning of 'run him out' has opposite meaning.

> In the oId days, before Mackenna ran him out of the territory...

From 'Mackenna's Gold' film.

Answer (score 3):

They are just different idiomatic expressions with the verb "run":

***[Run (one) out (of some place)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+someone+out)***:

> To chase one away with force or the threat of force or punishment.
>
> - *The sheriff ran the bandits out of town last winter, but it looks like they're back again. The security guard ran us out before we could sneak into the warehouse.*

***Run out (on)***:

> To abandon a romantic relationship with one. Often followed by "on (someone)."
>
> - *I don't know what I'll do if Sarah runs out on me. I thought Jack really loved me, but he ran out as soon as I wasn't earning as much money as I used to*.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: I  saw translation that it means 'run from her'. I think 'I toId you nobody runs me out.' means 'I toId you nobody runs from me.' but why?

Comment: I must say I think it's a bit "odd" for that dictionary definition to "particularise" the sense of ***to run out on** = **to abandon*** as being specifically relevant to the ending of a romantic relationship.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  - It appears to be a sense suggested also by other dictionaries: [run out on someone] to suddenly leave your wife, husband, or partner
*Jane’s husband ran out on her when their children were still young*. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run-out-on - https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/run-out-on

Comment: @Vitaly - what means "run from her"? Which translation are you referring to?  She *ran me out* means she sent me away. She *ran out (on) me* means she left me.

Comment: It was about 'run out on her' But for me the main question was about 'run me out' on the end of a sentense, Can I replace it into 'run out me' 'leave me' 'run out on me' or 'run from me'.

Comment: @Vitaly - run from me has a different meaning, see here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+from

Comment: @user070221: I think it's more a matter of saying *some* dictionaries give example usages where it's contextually implicit that the person being ***abandoned, deserted*** was previously in a "romantic relationship" with the one running out on him/her. But the phrasal verb is equally applicable to a parent deserting their children, or in fact more or less *any* person who leaves someone / something (to whom / which they had previously professed allegiance). It just seems pointlessly unnecessary to single out the "romantic" context, which I *don't* think is even "implicit" in the usage itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are two completely different phrasal verbs here...

> 1: ***to run*** [someone] **out** [**of** (some location)]
>    *- to chase [someone] away with force or the threat of force or punishment.* [(thefreedictionary)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+someone+out+of+town)
>
> 2: ***to run out on*** [someone]
>    *- to abandon or leave [someone].* [(thefreedictionary)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+someone+out+of+town)

Note that there are several other phrasal verbs involving ***to run***, including (but not limited to)...

> 3: ***to run out*** [of something]
>    *- to finish, use, or sell all of something, so that there is none left.* [(Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-out)
>
> 4: ***to run into*** [someone]
>    *- to meet [someone] by chance.* [(Oxford Learners Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/run-into)

Comment: so 'run me out' the same as 'run out me' can mean 'to leave' or not?

Comment: @Vitaly - No, we wouldn't say "run out me"; that doesn't make any sense.  Neither one means "to leave".  "Jim ran Bob out" means Jim **made** Bob leave.

Comment: @stangdon: Grrr! Your comment reminds me that the ***of** [some location]* element isn't *necessarily* required in usage #1 above. Which I had *considered* at time of writing my answer, but decided to ignore because it would require slightly awkward typography. Ho hum! I guess I'd better edit it in. (Better to be ***precise*** than ***concise**!* :)